# Using MySql.Data with C# while not making a MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql.data

The reccomended way to use MySql.Data is to NOT use a MySqlConnection object; as explained in the documentation.  This allows for the MySQl.Data API code to handle connection pooling correctly.
See: [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html)

So, for example, this code Selects data with the connection string passed in as a parameter.

The MySqlConnection object is created in the background:

```
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from cfx_jobs", _mySqlConnectionString);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
```

I have looked around and I cannot find an example of how to Insert into the database without explicitly creating a MySqlConnection object.

Which method should I use?

Comment: if using a DataAdapter, make your changes to the dataset and then call adapter.update(dataset) to update database with any changes

Comment: `it is best to let the connection pooling system manage all connections. Do not create a globally accessible instance of MySqlConnection and then manually open and close it.`  Methinks the operative phrase is **globally accessible**.  That said, if you create a 'global' DataAdapter and configure it, it will retain the MySqlCommand object to INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE as well as manage the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it.

```
MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(_mySqlConnectionString, sqlStatement);
```